# ui path web scrape format

Tags: format, scrape, rpa, uipath

I'm trying to do a web data scape on a shopping list at [shopgun.com](https://shopgun.com/lists) by using the RPA program Ui Path. But i fail to extract data of the elements that have been striked through eg. <del>milk</del>.

I have succesfull extraced the list of all elements, but I need to tell which is done and which are not. Example of a list with object striked through [Shopping list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oawap.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the html class of the items added into the list and then differentiate the item on the basis of the html class. The items which are done have different class while the remaining ones have different class. In this way you will be able to get the different items.

Answer (score 0):

Please use following class in the element selector:

class="ListItem__ItemTitle-a9q82c-6 jKHKBF"

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: That selector is too specific. `a9q82c-6 jKHKBF` is a random generated ID that changes on updates. Using such a selector would require a lot of maintenance and thus not desired.